# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java

пытаюсь собрать jar-ник и запустить его через терминал. ругается что не находит класс  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, хотя библиотека mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar лежит папке libs, которая лежит в корне jar-ника. manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar
Main-Class: Main
```

стектрейс:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at MySql.connect(MySql.java:48)
at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

ошибка в этой части:

```
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Class.forName(driverName);
```

банальный вопрос, но почему так происходит?

Comment: версия JDK какая?

Comment: Выведите на печать `CLASSPATH` и сразу все станет на свои места.

Comment: кто же сует jar в jar. киньте библиотеку рядом с jar файлом и будет вам счастье

Comment: в Classpath все библиотеки прописаны.